# how can i compare matched data in many tables mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i need to compare many tables to find data match with first one 
ex:

```
Tbl 1:
ID|name|security number
1 |Mina|1234
2 |Magd|4568
3 |amy |8856

Tbl 2
ID|name|security number
1 |rrr |1234
2 |aaa |223
3 |bbb |115

Tbl 3
ID|name|security number
1 |ccc|1234
2 |ddd|990
3 |vvv|1001
```

result is 
tbl_1.ID = 1 Mina , is like tbl.2.name = rrr , is like tbl.3.name = ccc

Comment: It would be nice to see what it was that you tried in order to have resolved this yourself, which would have shown us that you did research this before posting the question. 
**When you try, you also learn.** If someone just gives you an answer/solution, it would have all been for nothing and I say this for the/your future. 
You can then edit your post to contain something that may have failed; even that shows an effort on your part. Remember, we're always glad to help.

Comment: If you haven't yet read up on JOINS, do. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: i've found this solution

SELECT    tbl_1.id , tbl_1.name
FROM      tbl_1
WHERE     tbl_1.id IN(SELECT tbl_2.ID FROM tbl_2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found this mysql query that solved my problem

```
SELECT    tbl_1.id , tbl_1.name FROM      tbl_1 WHERE tbl_1.id IN (SELECT tbl_2.ID FROM tbl_2);
```

thanks for your time and support